# Why turn off programs in wine

Tags: 16.04, wine

I have issue with programs which are ruining in wine. When I start some application it automatically close after few minutes. What I missed? There is some setting which do that? How to fix it?

With terminal program not starting. Please find outpoot:

```
wine MetaTrade64.exe
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0x350000 0 0x23f3d0 4 stub
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:nls:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 0x2389a4, 0x2389c0 0x2389a0
fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 0x2389a4 0x2389c0 0x2389a0) returning a dummy value (current locale)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0xbfe550 (nil)): stub
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0x350000 0 0x23f3d0 4 stub
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:nls:GetThreadPreferredUILanguages 00000038, 0x2389a4, 0x2389c0 0x2389a0
fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x38 0x2389a4 0x2389c0 0x2389a0) returning a dummy value (current locale)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000060)
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0xbfe550 (nil)): stub
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\MetaTrade64.exe"
```

Comment: It might be that some features are not well supported by Wine. In any case you will need to start the program by using the terminal in order to see any output message that is shown by Wine right after the crash. Then you will need to update your question with that information.

Comment: Via terminal program not starting. Outpoot:

Comment: Well, you have to provide the **correct** path to the `.exe` file.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the executable full path :

wine "C:\Program Files\MetaTrade\MetaTrade64.exe" for example. Wine is complaining that it cannot find the executable

Regards